# Groebner basis with group action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algorithms, rt.representation-theory

At one point my advisor, Mark Haiman, mentioned that it would be nice if there was a way to compute Groebner bases that takes into account a group action.

> Does anyone know of any work done along these lines?

For example, suppose a general linear group $G$ acts on a polynomial ring $R$ and we have an ideal $I$ invariant under the group action. Suppose we have a Groebner basis $B$ of $I$. Then we can form the set  $G(B) := \{ G(b) : b \in B \}$. Perhaps we also wish to form the set
$$IG(B) := \{ V : V \text{ is an irreducible summand of } W, \text{ for some }W \in G(B) \}$$
(note that $G(b)$ cyclic implies it has a multiplicity-free decomposition into irreducibles).

> Can we find a condition on a set of $G$-modules (resp. $G$-irreducibles), analogous to Buchberger's S-pair criterion, that guarantees that this set is of the form $G(B)$ (resp. $IG(B)$) for some Groebner basis $B$?
>
> Can the character of $R /I$ be determined from the set $IG(B)$ in a similar way to how the Hilbert series of $R /I$ can be determined from $B$?

Comment: Note that no change to the standard theory is necessary if $G$ is a torus -- now we're just talking multigraded Hilbert series, rather than usual.

Comment: You've probably already found this, but [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1530) sets up a theory of equivariant Gröbner bases, though I think not quite of the type you seek.

Comment: I didn't know about this, and it looks quite interesting even if it's not exactly what I'm asking for. Thank you!

Comment: Any luck? I'd also like to hear about this!

Comment: Two comments: (1) To get braces to appear, you have to use two backslashes: \\{, provided Markdown doesn't edit this comment.  This is because Markdown converts backslash-brace to brace, so to get backslash-brace, you must use backslash-backslash-brace.  (2) Clark, you should post your link as an answer, and if it's what Jonah was looking for, you should accept it, and otherwise maybe comment on it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the old paper [Symbolic solution of polynomial equation systems with symmetry](http://opus.kobv.de/zib/volltexte/1990/31/pdf/SC-90-03.pdf) by Karin Gatermann?  Or [Zeros of equivariant vector fields: Algorithms for an invariant approach](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.41.6148&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Patrick Worfolk?

There is also the more recent work [Equivariant Groebner bases and the Gaussian two-factor model](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2009arXiv0908.1530B) by Brouwer and Draisma, as well as [Solving Systems of Polynomial Equations with Symmetries Using SAGBI-Gröbner Bases](http://www-calfor.lip6.fr/~jcf/Papers/ISSAC09a.pdf) by Faugere and Rahmany?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the paper [Groebner bases of ideals invariant under endomorphisms](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510589) by Drensky and La Scala.