# Lie $2$-groups and differential equations

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, lie-groups, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I was reading the abstract of a recent preprint ([Division Algebras and Supersymmetry III](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.3574) by Juhn Huerta), and I wondered if something much simpler than what he was talking about had been worked on: have [Lie $2$-groups](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie+2-group) been applied to the resolution of differential equations, in the same manner that Lie groups [originated](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387950001) from the study of differential equations?

In other words, do Lie 2-groups arise as *symmetries* for (certain kinds of) differential equations, and can these in turn be used for the integration/resolution of those same differential equations?  If they do not, then in what setting can a 2-group be understood as a symmetry (if any), and to what 'use' can this information be put?

My motivation here is to expand the toolset I can use to solve problems in classical analysis (like differential equations), and **not** to explore the other areas where Lie groups have developed in to (like Lie algebras and their classification, etc).  For the purposes of this question, these issues are out-of-scope.  In-scope are applications (to classical analysis) of generalizations going all the way to [$\infty$-Lie groupoids](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/smooth+infinity-groupoid).

Comment: It seems to me that the role of symmetries for solving differential equations is not much different from the role of symmetries for solving systems of algebraic equations. So maybe (at least to me) it would make sense to first ask the easier question: what are "higher" symmetries of a variety, and how can they be used to solve algebraic equations?

Comment: @Michael:  Do you have references for the explicit use of symmetries for solving systems of algebraic equations?  The most trivial ones (i.e. when a system factors) are used, but work with other symmetries actually being leveraged is rarer.  By this I mean that I have not seen symmetries show up in Groebner basis algorithms very often, except in the 4 papers I linked to here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12039/groebner-basis-with-group-action.  What did I miss?

Comment: @Michael: Lets my comment is mis-interpreted - I agree with you, I just don't know if this work has already been done for *symmetries* in the multivariate case.

Comment: Jacques, sorry I don't have any references for the use of symmetries in solving algebraic equations and my comment was more of a spontaneous  reaction after being intrigued by your question and Urs answer (which is also beyond my current understanding). My vague reasoning was that algebraic equations are a very degenerate case of differential equation (zero independent variables, or zero order). So if the question makes sense for differential equations it should also make sense for algebraic ones.

Comment: The link between differential equations and algebraic equations is very subtle - see for example the preprint http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.4508 by Chen and Kauers for a hint.  And algebraic equations are not 'degenerate' differential equations as they are non-linear in the dependent variable, while DEs are 'linear' (in an appropriate sense).  Of course one can get a DE from an algebraic equation, but not in a (useful) unique way.  [Read the paper linked above before commenting on that point, please!]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A well-studied special case of higher symmetries of differential equations is that of differential equations that arise as [Euler-Lagrange equations](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Euler-Lagrange+equation) of local action functionals. The symmetries and symmetries-of-symmetries and symmetries-of-symmetries-of-symmetries of such a system of equations form an $\infty$-groupoid whose infinitesimal version is encoded by the corresponding [BRST complex](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/BRST+complex) -- which is the [Chevalley-Eilenberg algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chevalley-Eilenberg+algebra) of the corresponding [L-∞ algebroid](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie+infinity-algebroid). In simple cases (or else locally) this is the global quotient by a [smooth ∞-group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/smooth+infinity-group): the "ghosts" in the BRST complex are the cotangents to the local symmetries, the "ghosts-of-ghosts" are the cotangents to the local symmetries-of-symmetries, and so on.

For instance

- for the action functional of the [Yang-Mills field](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yang-Mills%20field) the symmetries form an ordinary Lie group;
- for the action functional of the [Kalb-Ramond field](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kalb-Ramond%20field) the symmetries form the [circle 2-group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/circle%20n-group) $\mathbf{B}U(1) = (U(1) \to 1)$, (or rather the 2-group of functions with values in the circle 2-group);
- for the action functional of the [supergravity C-field](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/supergravity%20C-field) the symmetries are governed by the [circle 3-group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/circle%20n-group) $\mathbf{B}^2 U(1) = (U(1) \to 1 \to 1)$;
- the [higher abelian Chern-Simons theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/higher+dimensional+Chern-Simons+theory) in dimension $4k+3$ has the [circle (2k+1)-group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/circle%20n-group) $\mathbf{B}^{2k} U(1)$ as its gauge group;
- the symmetries of full [string field theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string%20field%20theory) form a general $\infty$-group (not an $n$-group for any finite $n$) the structure of which nobody really understands, I think.
- every [∞-Chern-Simons theory](http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/infinity-Chern-Simons+theory) (or equivalently its Euler-Lagrange equations) has a higher group of symmetries. In general, this is not just a higher gauge group, but even a higher gauge *groupoid* .

  - the gauge groupoid of the [Poisson sigma-model](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Poisson%20sigma-model) is controled by the [Lie integration](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie%20integration) of a [Poisson Lie algebroid](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Poisson+Lie algebroid), which is a [symplectic+groupoid](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symplectic groupoid);
  - the gauge 2-groupoid of the [Courant sigma-model](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Courant%20sigma-model) is controled by the Lie integration of a [Courant Lie 2-algebroid](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Courant+Lie+2-algebroid), which is a [symplectic Lie 2-algebroid](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symplectic+infinity-groupoid);
  - the gauge $n$-groupoid of a grade $n$ [AKSZ sigma-model](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/AKSZ+sigma-model) is similarly controled by a [symplectic Lie n-groupoid](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symplectic+infinity-groupoid).
  - the 7-dimensional "[fivebrane Chern-Simons theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/differential+fivebrane+structure)" has [string 2-group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/string%202-group)-symmetries

Comment: This is a better-than-hoped for answer for half of my question, thank you.  Any idea about the other half: do we actually know how to use these generalized symmetries to 'integrate' (in the sense used in Peter Olver's excellent book) these fields?

Comment: The (higher) space of solutions of these differential equations is the derived critical locus (http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/derived+critical+locus) of the corresponding action functional, which is the space of solutions, up to homotopy, modulo the higher gauge symmetries, up to homotopy. This higher derived space is famously modeled, dually, by the full BV-BRST complex (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/BV-BRST+formalism). Physicists have been using this since the 80s without knowing about higher and derived geometry. But that's precisely what it is about.

Comment: Two further remarks:  1) I had said that the above comment applies to Euler-Lagrange equations of an action functional. But in fact the BV-BRST formalism works more generally, for arbitrary differential equations. Some references in this direction are listed here: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/BV-BRST+formalism#ReferencesForNonLagrangianEquations

2) the super-L-infinity algebra symmetries that John Huerta discusses were discovered by D'Auria and Fre as the symmetries of the differential equations of higher supergravity: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/D%27Auria-Fre+formulation+of+supergravity

Comment: I am sure that the answer to my question is indeed buried in there - it is just quite beyond my current state of knowledge of these matters for me to understand that answer.  Sigh.  I'll accept the answer.  I guess what I really meant to ask is: have these led to concrete algorithms to solve certain equations (in ``closed form''!), like 1-Lie groups have?  I am having fun trying to understand enough of the background to understand your answer, but eventually that is what I am after.

Comment: I am not aware of concrete algorithms for solving differential equations coming out of this formalism, sorry. This formalism has a different aim: it is all about providing concrete prescriptions for obtaining the canonical symplectic form on the space of solutions modulo gauge transformation (for the case of Euler-Lagrange PDEs, at least). But maybe there is more to be said than has been worked out.