# Exploiting symmetries to speed up Groebner basis calculation?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algorithms

Take a collection $F$ of homogeneous polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, along with a finite group $G$ of linear operators over $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that for every $f\in F$ and $g\in G$, we have $f\circ g\in F$. Can one exploit these symmetries to produce speedups in computing a Groebner basis for $\langle F\rangle$?

[Faugère and Rahmany's work](http://www-polsys.lip6.fr/~jcf/Papers/ISSAC09a.pdf) suggests that speedups are available when $G$ is a group of permutations, but the applications I have in mind do not use such groups.

[This question is related](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12039/groebner-basis-with-group-action), but computation time doesn't appear to be a consideration there.